# Add Header to an ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I want to add an image as header to a ListView. It happens to work - BUT there is much space around the image, although i have tried changing the paddings... it does not work.

this is my main activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/LV_Home"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView 
android:src="@drawable/homeimage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how i added the header:

```
String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.entries);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LV_Home);
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_main_menue, null);
lv.addHeaderView(header);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: You can also do that in xml only, without the need of code. It's easier, I think. I add my headers (and footers) that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/homeimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/LV_Home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And comment out these lines:

```
/*
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_main_menue, null);
lv.addHeaderView(header);
lv.setAdapter(aa);
*/
```

Note that now you have only one xml instead of two (the header is now included in the ListView's layout)

Comment: Hello Tobor,

thanks for your input. I used to add Headers like this before, but i read in the documentation, that you should use the addHeaderView method. But i think i should do it with one xml only, like you suggested - i had no problems with that yet =)

Comment: Well, with this design you also have **one LinearLayout less**, so you improve the **flattening** of your hierarchy